# jquery convert date to formated date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery/javascript and trying to convert date format to date with date+hours minute seconds.
I tried with new Date(myFormatDate) but it gave me complete date including timezone. Is substring of new Date() is only option to get to my format?

```
From Format I am trying to convert 
"2018-05-17T00:55:46"

To Format I am trying to achieve
2018-05-01 23:17:32.00
```

Comment: that's a whole 'nother time there

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way for you if want this specific case:

```
var someDate = new Date("2018-05-17T00:55:46");
var formatted = someDate.toISOString().slice(0,10) + " " + someDate.toISOString().slice(11,22);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this function will help you

```
var d = new Date();

function FormatDate(DateToConvert){
return  DateToConvert.getFullYear() + '-' + (DateToConvert.getMonth()+ 1) + '-' + DateToConvert.getDate() + " " + DateToConvert.getHours() + ":" + DateToConvert.getMinutes() + ":" + DateToConvert.getSeconds() + ':' + DateToConvert.getMilliseconds();}

console.log(FormatDate(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an additional library like moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)

Following are couple of examples

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // May 23rd 2018, 8:41:58 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Wednesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // May 23rd 18
```